# How to migrate a database that uses master db stored procedures to Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

We have a sql2k8 database that uses sp_xml_preparedocument, a master db system extended stored procedure, that needs to go to Azure. The migration tools (SSMS2016 wizard) give a validation error: SQL71501 that [dbo].[sp_xml_preparedocument] is a missing reference, when validating the export.

I can't see any way to reference the sp so it can be migrated. Intellisense always shows an error too.

Comment: The treatment of the master database in Azure is a bit different and this may be a symptom of the fact that it is not a perfect analog of the on-premise master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you first verify that your code works fine on Azure SQL when you manually execute the scripts? When I execute queries with sp_xml_preparedocument from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx) on my Azure SQL Database it works fine.

If your code works, then it is a problem in SSMS migration assistant, so in that case you should report bug on [SQL Server Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback), with some minimized repro script, so SQL Server team can fix it.

Comment: Yes thanks, we ended up having to migrate by commenting out the references and then uncommenting once the db had been moved over. As far as I know the system works in Azure SQL, just that the migration tool was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server 2016 Enterprise with Service Pack 1 (x64) . The SP1 should support Azure DB . The 2012 version of Sql server might do iT.

Comment: I think we are using SSMS2k16, don't know what Service Pack, but not sure if SQL Azure is the issue here - it's failing on validating the export , even if I just verify by running the Export bacpac/dacpac. It seems it cannot recognized referenced SPs in master